# Div getting attached to h1 in chrome

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a bar at the top of my page like stackoverflow has, the black one on the top.

And I am trying to create a heading underneath it.

```
<html>
<style>
.top{
    background-color: black;
    position:fixed;
    height: 50px;
    width: 110%;
    float: top;
    margin-left: -10px;
    margin-top: -10px;
}

h1{
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 100px;
}
</style>
<body>
    <div class = "top">
        asdfad
        fasdfasdf
    </div>
    <h1> lol </h1>
</body>
</html>
```

However when I create this in Chrome, the div top is getting attached to H1, like occupying half of its size. What is wrong ?

Comment: the `position:fixed;` makes top bar to overlay your H1..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want your menu bar to has `fixed` position so just add `top:0` to this class:

```
.top{
    background-color: black;
    position:fixed;
    height: 50px;
    width: 110%;
    /*float: top;   remove this*/
    margin-left: -10px;
    margin-top: -10px;
    top:0 /*add this*/
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m2V8L/2/)

Additional there is no `float:top`. Take a look here [css float property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_float.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
margin-top:100px;
```

To:

```
padding-top:100px;
```

To have the `h1` displayed

You can also use:

```
* {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
```

To get rid of the white space on top

**P.S:**

- Wasn't just a Chrome issue.
- `float:top;` is not a valid `float` property.

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/RDzmN/4/)**